# Where can I find my DB URL to successfully store items in the DB?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I'm following this tutorial https://appdividend.com/2018/03/23/react-js-laravel-file-upload-tutorial/ to store image file path inside MySQL DB.

In my axios post request, the URL is a dummy one.  How do I find out what my URL is for my DB?  I can't seem to find it anywhere.  I'm using MySQL workbench if that matters.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios, { post } from 'axios';

class Wall extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            image: ''
        };

        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this);
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.fileUpload(this.state.image);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
        if(!files.length) {
            return;
        }

        this.createImage(files[0]);
    }

    createImage(file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            this.setState({
                image: e.target.result
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    fileUpload(image){
        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/fileupload';
        const formData = {file: this.state.image};
        return  axios.post(url, formData)
            .then(response => console.log(response));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>File Upload</h1>
                <input type="file" />
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Wall;
```

Here's my FileUploadController.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FileuploadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->get('file'))
        {
            $image = $request->get('file');
            $name = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($image, 0, strpos($image, ';')))[1])[1];
            \Image::make($request->get('file'))->save(public_path('images/').$name);
        }



        $fileupload = new Fileupload();
        $fileupload->filename=$name;
        $fileupload->save();
        return response()->json('Successfully added');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to access db from your server side code

Comment: In your termina type `php artisan route:list` this way you can see what routes are registered in your application

Comment: @charlietfl just posted my server side code

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `config/app.php` and look for `aliases` `'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class`

and you can use this to your controller by doing like so:

```
use DB;
```

See below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class FileuploadController extends Controller
{

    // ......

}
```

and see more details about `DB` queries here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: tried this, but still no file paths are being recorded in the DB upon clicking submit for some reason :(

Comment: try this one and you can see the file path:


 $response =   \Image::make($request->get('file'))->save(public_path('images/').$name);

dd($response);

Comment: hey, hope all is well.  my bad to come back a day later but, do you know where I can find my database URL to make my axios post request (send info the DB)?  the above url `http://localhost:8000/api/fileupload` is the one from the tutorial I linked.  But how do I find my own?